# AngularFire single object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

In the angularFire examples it shows how to get a collection of objects from firebase.

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'angularFireCollection',
  function($scope, $timeout, angularFireCollection) {    
    var url = 'https://ex.firebaseio.com/stuff';
    $scope.col = angularFireCollection(url);
  }
]);
```

What about a single object only?

I tried something like this:

```
  fb.child('stuff/'+id).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    $scope.obj = snapshot.val();
    console.log('hey got the value')
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  });
```

Doesn't seem to work. The console outputs the object value correctly but the controller doesn't update.

Comment: As for why your attempt didn't work: when modifying $scope outside of an angular function (like in that Firebase callback), you need to manually trigger a $digest with $scope.$apply(). There's a pretty good explanation here: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the regular angularFire service, and specifying the type of your single object:

```js
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'angularFire',
  function($scope, $timeout, angularFire) {    
    var url = 'https://ex.firebaseio.com/stuff';
    angularFire(url, $scope, "obj", "");
  }
]);
```

Note the 4th argument (" " means string, you can also use booleans, numbers, objects and arrays).

Comment: I get `Error: type mismatch `

Comment: Is the single object at the URL a string? You have to change the 4th argument to be an object of the same type as what's at "https://ex.firebaseio.com/stuff" or what you plan to store there. Also make sure to use the latest version of the library: http://firebase.github.io/angularFire/angularFire.js

Comment: It's an object so it worked after I replace the quotes with brackets. This API makes no sense to me though, I initially tried putting "object" as the last argument. Is there some documentation for this? What do you think about standardizing / allowing the same api for single objects and collections so we don't have to load multiple providers (hopefully using the correct terminology)?